# Extract number of a Result Command of R

Tags: r

I had the following result

```
> z<-fitdist(p2, "gamma", method="mge", gof="AD2")    #where p2 is a data sample
> z

Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum goodness-of-fit 
Parameters:
        estimate
shape 0.28831646
rate  0.03594412
```

If I use

```
> z$estimate
        estimate
shape 0.28831646
rate  0.03594412
```

I'm trying to put the number of Shape and Rate at a specific and separate variable.
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Have you try `z$estimate[1]` or `z$estimate["shape"]` ?

Comment: Which package to use to compute `fitdist()` ? You can access the structure of your object with `str()`. So here given the other answers you should see with `str(z$estimate)` that it is either a list or a data.frame and access the information accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
z$estimate["shape"]
z$estimate["rate"]
```

to get the number values, or also

```
z$estimate[1]
z$estimate[2]
```